# What is the exact value of the incoming request URI that Nginx matches against its location directive?

Tags: nginx, url

Wikipedia defines [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax as having this formula:

URI = scheme ":" ["//" authority] path ["?" query] ["#" fragment]

Nginx docs claims that [location](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) is related to the normalized incoming URI.

However, when we want to write our `location` directives, most examples assume that they are dealing with `path`, and not the entire URI.

So, what is the exact value in standards terminology that Nginx delivers us in is `location` directive?

Comment: In that Wikipedia article it is the part called "path". It has been fully decoded, always begins with a `/` and multiple consecutive `/`s are folded into one. That is the normalised URI used by `location` and `rewrite` statements and can be found in the `$uri` variable.

Comment: When creating an nginx virtual host, you are specifying an server name and the port to listen. From these two you have the scheme and the domain name. 
The the location directive applies after all this